# wrapAll not wrapping plain text

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is some HTML that looks like this:

```
  <body>
    Do
    all
    declarations for
    the same
    <TT>static</TT> function
    or variable
    have to include the storage class <TT>static</TT>?
  </body>
```

When I do `$('body').children().wrapAll("<div class='container'><div class='row'><div class='col-md-12'></div></div></div>");` to wrap everything into a `.container`, it works except it doesn't encompass the plain text:

```
  <body>
   <div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
     <div class='col-md-12'>
      <TT>static</TT>
      <TT>static</TT>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
    Do
    all
    declarations for
    the same
    function
    or variable
    have to include the storage class ?
  </body>
```

How do I fix this so it preserves the original structure?

Comment: Try `.contents()` instead of `.children()` - the latter explicitly excludes text nodes.

Comment: The answers show why what you have isn't working. `.wrapInner()` would also work for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/gwky4o60/

Answer (score 2):

`children` does not return text nodes.  You will need to use `contents`.

```
$('body').contents().wrapAll("<div class='container'><div class='row'><div class='col-md-12'></div></div></div>");
```

```js
$(function(){
  $('#children').children().wrapAll("<div class='container'><div class='row'><div class='col-md-12'></div></div></div>");

  $('#contents').contents().wrapAll("<div class='container'><div class='row'><div class='col-md-12'></div></div></div>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>With Children:</h2>
<div id="children">
Do
    all
    declarations for
    the same
    <TT>static</TT> function
    or variable
    have to include the storage class <TT>static</TT>?
 </div>

<h2>With Contents:</h2>
<div id="contents">
Do
    all
    declarations for
    the same
    <TT>static</TT> function
    or variable
    have to include the storage class <TT>static</TT>?
 </div>
```